# What should be the argument to a void recursive reverse function of linked list, if head is declared locally inside main?

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, reverse

I'm trying to implement a recursive reversal of a linked list. Along with providing a node* pointer as an argument, what should I give as an argument?

This function is when the head is declared locally in main. I successfully implemented this function when the head is declared globally since we do not need to pass the address of head explicitly(as it is accessible inside the function).

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std ;

struct node{
int data ;
node* link ;
};

void insert(int n, node** head)
{
node* temp = new node() ;
temp->link = NULL ;
temp->data = n ;
if(*head == NULL)
{
    *head = temp ;
}
else
{
    node* ptr = *head ;
    while(ptr->link != NULL)
    {
        ptr = ptr->link ;
    }
    ptr->link = temp ;
}
}

void print(node* ptr)
{   
while(ptr != NULL)
{
    cout<<ptr->data<<" " ;
    ptr = ptr->link ;
}
}

void reverse(node* ptr, node** hptr)
{   
node* temp = *hptr ;
if(ptr->link == NULL)
{
    *hptr = ptr ;
    return ;
}
ptr = ptr->link ;
reverse(ptr, &temp) ; //Line 10: Here is the main doubt. I want to write an equivalent of &head instead of &temp to pass the original address of head.
node* q = ptr->link ;
q->link = ptr ;
ptr->link = NULL ;
}

int main()
{   
node* head = NULL ; //local head declaration
insert(5,&head) ;
insert(6,&head) ;
insert(7,&head) ;
insert(8,&head) ;
reverse(head,&head) ;
cout<<endl ;
print(head) ;
}
```

When the linked list is 5->6->7->8, there is no error and nothing is printed when I print this linked list. 
The expected answer is 8->7->6->5 .
How do I rectify line 10, or any other error in my code?

Code with global head:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std ;

struct node{
int data ;
node* link ;
};

node* head ;

void reverse(node* ptr) //pointer to node
{
if((ptr->link) == NULL) //exit condition
{
    head = ptr ;
    return;
}

else
{
    reverse(ptr->link) ;
    node* q = ptr->link ; //temp variable that points to the adjacent(right) node of ptr 
    q->link = ptr ;
    ptr->link = NULL ;
}

}

void print(node* ptr)
{
if (ptr == NULL)
{
    return ;
}
else
{
    cout<<ptr->data<<" " ;
    ptr = ptr->link ;
    print(ptr) ;
}

}

int main()
{
head = NULL ;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    node* temp = new node() ;
    temp->link = NULL ;
    temp->data = i ;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp ;
    }
    else
    {
        node* p = head ;
        while(p->link != NULL)
        {
            p = p->link ;
        }
        p->link = temp ;
    }

}

reverse(head) ;
print(head) ;


return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Stop messing around with raw pointers in c++, YAGNI.

Comment: So you have a version working with a global head, what stops you using exactly the same code except passing head as a node** parameter? I don't see the problem. Maybe you should post the working version with the global head as well.

Comment: Pointer code is really hard to read, but the thing that looks strange to me is that in the code above `hptr` starts as the head pointer but then when you make the recursive call you make it point at something else. Why do you do that if it's supposed to be the head pointer?

Comment: In other words why don't you write `reverse(ptr, hptr);` (and remove `temp`)?

Comment: @john I just wanted to test my knowledge of pointers and therefore tried to implement the same using a local head. The doubt I'm having is in Line 10.

Comment: @AbishekSeshan I know that, I'm just not understanding why it isn't easy. if you already have a working version with a global head.

Comment: @john That's exactly what I did first before including a temp.. doesn't work. No output again.

Comment: @AbishekSeshan I can't be bothered to figure out pointer code, please post the code for the working version with a global head, and I'll take a look.

Comment: @john I'm new to stack overflow... Should I post the global head code in continuation with this code or somewhere else?

Comment: Just put it in the question above.

Comment: @AbishekSeshan Well I think I figured it out anyway. See answer below. I think you must have introduced a bug when you removed the global variable.

Answer (score 1):

This version works for me

```
void reverse(node* ptr, node** hptr)
{   
    if (ptr->link == NULL)
    {
        *hptr = ptr;
        return;
    }
    reverse(ptr->link, hptr);
    node* q = ptr->link;
    q->link = ptr;
    ptr->link = NULL;
}
```

The problem with the version above was the assignment `ptr = ptr->link;` immediately before the recursive call. Plus the incorrect treatment of the head pointer.